# MoveIt Difficulties with end-effector Pose transformation for humanoid robot

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, moveit, ros-melodic, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Distro: Melodic

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

MoveIt compiled from sources

OpenManipulator-P + RH8D

**Problem Description:**

We have two different Ik_systems (one ROS/MoveIt, one custom) for our humanoid robot. We'd like to experiment with them with regard to the quality of ik_solutions. When comparing ik_solutions of our two ik systems, we noticed, that we have severe differences between the orientation of our ROS IK solution and the Custom IK solution, while they visually seem to be extremely close.

We figured there is a difference between the coordinate system of our custom implementation and the ROS one. Next step was to compare the values of our Homing Pose. The Homing Pose is set via Joint States, so the Joint Positions are exactly the same in both systems (also visual positions are identical). While the xyz position is exactly the same in both systems (difference per axis < 1e-08), the Orientation is completely different: **Custom System: [x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1]  MoveIt System: [x: -0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5, w: 0.5]**. Big problem for us is that due to this difference we are currently have tremendous problems executing some IK experiments.

We would like the Homing Pose Orientation to also be [x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1] (so that both of our systems are configured identically, we think our current problem will then vanish) but we are not able to transform it. Orientation always stays [x: -0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5, w: 0.5], I already modified the urdf, tried setPoseReferenceFrame in controller, nothing helps. Both systems use the same base_link and the same eef link. I looked up the Orientation of the base_link in rviz and it is  [x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1], so this seems correct for me.

Any idea how to fix this?

**Homing Pose:**
[image: Homing Pose]

**Kinematic Chain:**
[image: image description]

**MoveIt Orientation shown below, Expectation [0,0,0,1]**

`[INFO] Current Orientation:  r: 0.000000 p: 1.570796 y: 4.709419 ||  x: -0.499931 y: 0.501418 z: 0.500063 w: 0.498584`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384610/moveit-difficulties-with-end-effector-pose-transformation-for-humanoid-robot/) by [jangerrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/81600/jangerrit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-18**:\

> I would give you pictures but I do not have enough points

you do now.

Please do not post images of terminals, source code or `.launch`/`.urdf` or any other files though. Those all contain text or "are" text, so copy-paste those into your question.

**Comment by [jangerrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/81600/jangerrit/) on 2021-08-18**:
thank you really much

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-08-22**:
Please explain what "I already modified the urdf... nothing helps" means. Please describe the idea behind the change you make to the urdf. And what was the result?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-08-22**:
Sounds like you're not using the same end effector frame or planning frame in your custom IK and the ROS/MoveIt plugin.

**Comment by [jangerrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/81600/jangerrit/) on 2021-08-23**:
"I already modified the urdf" means I played around with the  tag of the joints where the coordinate frames change orientation, as shown in the last picture. It sometimes  broke urdf, sometimes did not have any effect as far as I could observe.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-08-23**:
Please explain in more detail in your post how you set up the IK and call it in your code, what your end effector links are, what your URDF and planning groups look like, and which outputs are different than what you expect. Also see the documentation for `getEndEffectorLink` and `setEndEffectorLink`

**Comment by [jangerrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/81600/jangerrit/) on 2021-08-23**:
Solved the Problem, it has nothing to do with the urdf. MoveIt just does not recognize our kinematic chain correctly.

Our kin. chain should look like the following:
r_arm:
base_link -> r_tool0

So what I did was:

- configure kin. chain for Planning Group in MoveIt setup_assistant as shown above
- execute `move_group->setPoseReferenceFrame("base_link")` in controller

Problem is getPlanningFrame() always returns "world" frame. So our custom IK system uses "base_link" as reference frame, while MoveIt uses "world". I discovered a lot of people experiencing this bug and there seems to be no solution, we will transform everything with tf2 now.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-08-23**:
@jangerrit I'm glad you figured it out. You should post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the Problem, it has nothing to do with the urdf. MoveIt just does not recognize our kinematic chain correctly.

Our kin. chain should look like the following: r_arm: base_link -> r_tool0

So what I did was:

- configure kin. chain for Planning
  Group in MoveIt setup_assistant as
  shown above
- execute
  move_group->setPoseReferenceFrame("base_link")
  in controller

Problem is getPlanningFrame() always returns "world" frame. So our custom IK system uses "base_link" as reference frame, while MoveIt uses "world". I discovered a lot of people experiencing this bug and there seems to be no solution, we will transform everything with tf2 now.

---

Originally posted by [jangerrit](https://answers.ros.org/users/81600/jangerrit/) with karma: 11 on 2021-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0